# REGEX - Capturar palabras de una frase en diferentes grupos

Tags: regex

Llevo un rato probando a seleccionar las palabras de una frase en grupos, para posteriormente poder hacer varias sustituciones. Ejemplo:

> alea iacta est
>
> de vita et moribus
>
> delirium tremens
>
> gratis et amore
>
> ibidem
>
> interposita persona
>
> motu proprio
>
> plus minusve

En la primera línea, debería obtener cinco o tres grupos (dependiendo de que se capturen o no los espacios en blanco, lo cual es irrelevante, ya que entre un grupo y otro siempre va a existir un espacio en blanco), a saber:

> grupo 1: alea
>
> grupo 2: iacta
>
> grupo 3: est

Lo que quisiera saber es si se puede hacer esto con una sola expresión regular, ya que no consigo dar con la solución. La expresión regular que se me ocurrió no funciona, que sería esta:

> (?:([a-zA-ZñÑáéíóúüÁÉÍÓÚÜ]+)(\s)?)+?\n

Imagino que no se puede conseguir lo que quiero, porque tampoco sería viable hacer posteriormente una sustitución al desconocer el número de grupos resultantes que se obtendrían. En los ejemplos que he puesto, las frases con más palabras tienen cuatro y la que menos una.

Edito para mayor claridad. No me importa el lenguaje de programación, quiero que funcione la regex sin necesidad de programación. Mi intención sería, por ejemplo, poder sustituir

> alea iacta est

por:

> 1 alea~iacta~est dle.rae.es/?w=alea+iacta+est

Un saludo y gracias.

Comment: Considera comentar en que lenguaje estas tratando de realizar esto, saludos.

Comment: Puedes, por favor, dar un poco más de detalles porque lo que entiendo es que quieres tener na expresión regular que obtenga cada palabra como grupo?

Comment: Jorgesys, no importa el lenguaje, me basta que funcione en la página https://regex101.com/ o una análoga. Juan Carlos Guibovitch, es como dices. Quiero que cada palabra de una misma línea, sea capturada como grupo diferente. Mi intención es poder sustituir alea iacta est por: 1 alea~iacta~est https://dle.rae.es/?w=alea+iacta+est

Comment: El lenguaje si importa verdaderamente, por ejemplo por JavaScript no me comería la cabeza y haría un split por espacios, separando cada palabra y dejando un array tal que así: ['alea', 'iacta', 'est']. Para el lenguaje en el que se esté programando debe exixtir un split (seguramente) pero en el caso en el que se quiera coger las palabras, el regex que te lo permite es /\w+/g. Pondré una respuesta con capturas enseñándote lo que sale en regex101.com a ver si es eso lo que buscas.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que se quiere es coger cada una de las palabras deberíamos mirar funciones de string (texto) que vienen definidas en los lenguajes de programación como `.split()` en JavaScript o python (entre muchos otros) y `.explode()` en PHP. Pero en el caso en el que se quiera coger palabras por expresiones regulares (regex) se deberán escoger con /\w+/g como se muestra a continuación en la página regex101.com:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

No definiste un lenguaje, ni quisiste definirlo, pero sí, es muy importante. La implementación de regex en cada lenguaje es **muy** diferente.

Lo que estás intentando es hacer que un mismo grupo capture múltiples veces al usar una estructura como

```
(re)+
```

Dependiendo del lenguaje, la respuesta:

- en [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) se puede. La coincidencia global es un `Match`, cada paréntesis genera un `Group`, y las múltiples instancias que captura cada paréntesis son `Captures`. Más info en [Docs](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.group.captures?view=netcore-3.1).
- en (creo que) todo el resto de los lenguajes, NO se puede. Pero solamente hay que encararlo de forma diferente. En vez de intentar que cada grupo capture múltiples veces, se hace que la coincidencia global sea 1 única palabra, y se trabaja con ese resultado. Para obtener todas las coincidencias en un texto, se usa el flag `/g` (o "global" -depende de cada lenguaje cómo configurarlo).

Ejemplo en JavaScript:

```js
const texto = 'alea iacta est',
      regex = /[a-zñáéíóúü]+/gi;
      
let resultado = texto.match(regex),
    formateado = resultado.join('~') + ' dle.rae.es/?w=' + resultado.join('+');

console.log(formateado);
```

Answer (score 0):

En Python:

```
import re
patron = re.compile("(\S+)")
m=patron.findall("abc def hhh")
print(m)
```

produce:

```
['abc', 'def', 'hhh']
```